# Authorization with new Office365 API

Tags: php, rest, odata, exchangewebservices, office365

I have started an attempt at utilizing the new Office 365 API. I am having some issues though.

I have successfully retrieved an access_token but the documentation doesn't tell me what to do with it.

Has anyone else done this successfully, or alternatively can you have a quick read over the documentation and shed some light on it?

Thanks

Edit: Forgot the link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The documentation to use PHP and Office365 API according to my research is almost inexistent but... I was able to use Office API by using this PHP class to process the oauth connection:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html

Hope it helps!

Using this class you will be able to access like this:

```
// Oauth to Office365
$office_oauth = new oauth_client_class;
$office_oauth->debug = true;
$office_oauth->debug_http = false;

$office_oauth->redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$office_oauth->client_id = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
$office_oauth->client_secret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';

$office_oauth->dialog_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&state={STATE}&scope={SCOPE}&resource='.UrlEncode("https://outlook.office365.com/");
$office_oauth->access_token_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token';

$office_oauth->oauth_version = 2;
$office_oauth->url_parameters = 1;
$office_oauth->authorization_header = 1;
$office_oauth->exit = 0;

$office_oauth->scope = 'YOUR_SCOPES';

if (($officeSuccess = $office_oauth->Initialize())) {

    $officeSuccess = $office_oauth->Process();
    $officeSuccess = $office_oauth->Finalize($officeSuccess);
}

if ($office_oauth->exit) {
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The access token should be [embedded in the request when calls the resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605895.aspx#ConNavExample_config) (please find the 9th). So I'm guessing you need to provide your access token in your request headers, for instance:

`context.SendingRequest2 += (s, e) =>
{
    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
};`